# Using a algorithm for searching a string in a vector

Tags: algorithm, vector, stl, count

Is it possible to count how many strings are equal to one given as a parameter using an algorithm method?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
int main(){
    vector<string> vectorPeople;
    //assume that myVector isn't empty
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    int total=std::count(myVector.begin(),myVector.end(),name);

 }
```

Comment: loop through each string in the vector using a `vector<string>::iterator`, and compare the strings to the parameter one-by-one

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah there's a method for that. and apart from that op explicitly asked for a method from the algorithm-API.

Comment: I marked this as "unclear what you're asking". There is an answer to the question already; but it contains essentially the same code you have in the question; and furthermore the question does not appear to have been edited so I think the code was there when the answer was written. Since the only question I can understand you to ask has already been answered in the question body, I can't imagine what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use `std::count` (you could've found that easily by a simple search).

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int count(std::vector<std::string> strings , std::string to_search){
    return std::count(strings.begin() , strings.end() , to_search);
}
```